# how to count classses in columns

Tags: sql-server, count

I'm trying to make a query and i'm having a bad time with one thing. Suppose I have a table that looks like this:

| id | Sample | Species | Quantity | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | AA | 5 | A |
| 2 | 1 | AB | 6 | A |
| 3 | 1 | AC | 10 | A |
| 4 | 1 | CD | 15 | C |
| 5 | 1 | CE | 20 | C |
| 6 | 1 | DA | 13 | D |
| 7 | 1 | DB | 7 | D |
| 8 | 1 | EA | 6 | E |
| 9 | 1 | EF | 4 | E |
| 10 | 1 | EB | 2 | E |

In the table I filter to have just 1 sample (but i have many), it has the species, the quantity of that species and a functional group (there are only five groups from A to E). I would like to make a query to group by the samples and make columns of the counts of the species of certain group, something like this:

| Sample | N_especies | Group A | Group B | Group C | Group D | Group E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 3 | 0 | 2 | 2 | 3 |

So i have to count the species (thats easy) but i don't know how to make the columns of a certain group, can anyone help me?

Comment: Turning rows into columns is called a "pivot". If you search on that term you can find examples and discussions. Conditional aggregation (as already noted) is much easier for simple situations like this with a fixed number of "values". Reporting tools can also easily do this if a "report" is your actual goal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

You can use PIVOT :

```
Select a.Sample,[A],[B],[C],[D],[E], [B]+[A]+[C]+[D]+[E] N_especies  from 
(select t.Sample,t.Grp from [WS_Database].[dbo].[test1] t) t
  PIVOT (
  COUNT(t.Grp)
  for t.Grp in ([A],[B],[C],[D],[E])
  ) a
```