# SQL Server 2016 - Transpose row to columns

Tags: sql-server, pivot-table, unpivot

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to transform table rows to columns where the number of rows included changes at the time of the query. Here's a sample of what I'm trying to do:

Characteristics Table

| strategy | year | month | aaa | aa | a |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| InvestmentA | 2020 | 12 | 5 | 4 | 10 |
| InvestmentB | 2020 | 12 | 8 | 15 | 25 |
| Investment(n) | 2020 | 12 | x | x | x |

Output

| year | month | Credit Type | InvestmentA | InvestmentA | Investment(n) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 12 | aaa | 5 | 8 | x |
| 2020 | 12 | aa | 4 | 15 | x |
| 2020 | 12 | a | 10 | 25 | x |

Comment: Do not use images to paste data, it is so much better to paste it as text, so we can copy and paste. Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69838896/how-to-count-classses-in-columns/69839279#69839279

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)